# Naming regression output in a double loop

Tags: r

I have a double loop looping over power and range, both go from 1 to 5. I would like to save all regression output in the following format: f12 where power=1 and range=2, etc.

I would like to save regression output in a table format using Stargazer, or something similar.

```r
# data:
y=rnorm(100, 0,1)
x=sample(5, 100, replace = T)

dat=data.frame(y=y, x=x)

# power & range:
range <- seq(1, 5, by = 1)
power <- seq(1, 5, by = 1)

# loop:

for (z in seq_along(power)) # power
{
  for (j in seq_along(range)) # range
  {
      # regression    
      dat$dummy.j <-  ifelse(range == j, 1 , 0 )
      f <- lm(y ~ poly(x, z, raw=TRUE) + dummy.j, data=dat, na.action=na.exclude)

      assign(paste("f", j, sep = ""), f)
  }

  assign(paste("f", z, sep = ""), f)
}

library(stargazer)
models_int <- list(f11, f12, f13, f14, f21, ....)
stargazer(models_int, type = "html", out="...")
```

I know that the second assign() is the problem, I just don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you save all results to a list? It saves you the trouble of typing 25 variable names.

Also, you want to have names as `f11`, `f12` ... . But what you actually create is only from `f1` to `f5`.

```
# loop:

results <- list()

for (z in seq_along(power)) # power
{
    for (j in seq_along(range)) # range
    {
        # regression    
        dat$dummy.j <-  ifelse(range == j, 1 , 0 )
        f <- lm(y ~ poly(x, z, raw=TRUE) + dummy.j, data=dat, na.action=na.exclude)

        current <- list(f)
        names(current) <- paste("f", z, j, sep = "")

        results <- append(results,current)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!